# Using ioprio_set() from linux kernel header ioprio.h in C++

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel

Pretty new to C++, and the ecosystem.

I'd like to use [ioprio_set(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ioprio_set) to lower the IO priority of a process to `IOPRIO_CLASS_IDLE`, but am having a few issues with the compiling / build toolchain aspects of it. I'm on a RHEL7 workstation with kernel 3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64, but this should ideally work on any Linux distribution.

I believe I need to `#include <linux/ioprio.h>` which associates to [this kernel header](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/ioprio.h). So I wrote this crappy hello world:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <linux/ioprio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    syscall(SYS_ioprio_set, IOPRIO_WHO_PROCESS, 0, IOPRIO_PRIO_VALUE(IO_PRIO_CLASS_BE,0));
    return 0;
}`
```

And attempted chanting a few incantations of this spell to the gcc gods:

`g++ -I/usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)/include -I/usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)/arch/x86/include -I/usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)/include/asm-generic hello_world.cpp`

Those all break in wonderful and spectacular ways, to the hint that I'm probably not supposed to be including them in userspace code. Digging a bit deeper and looking at the [source of the ionice](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/schedutils/ionice.c) utility in util-linux, it looks like I'm onto something as they've more or less re-implemented all of that in `ionice.c`.

What is the right approach for me to use? Should I continue banging at trying to include that header, which doesn't get installed to /usr/include/linux like all other "public" kernel headers, or should simply more or less port the code into my application copy/pasta style? There is a subtle hint about this on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921208/using-ioprio-set-in-c), but I need a bit more context if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't include headers from the kernel in userspace.
First, it will probably include and depend on different kernel configuration macros you haven't defined, and probably, the code itself won't link, as the code probably references external functions.

You have two options:

1. You missed the userspace header, if it available use that.
2. Implement the functionality in your code, assuming that there's a syscall/sysfs/sysctl for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It's not exactly true. Otherwise how libc can work with kernel?! There are headers for export and for internal usage.

Comment: you're correct.  the writer meant the internal ones obviously. hence my answer